# Pushforwards of Chow rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Briefly, which properties morphism should have to induce pushforward of Chow rings? It is said in both Hartshorne and [3264 and All That](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic720403.files/book.pdf) that it should be proper, but why not just closed?

Let $Z(X)$ be cycles on an algebraic variety $X$, i.e. linear combinations of (closed) subvarieties, and $Rat(X) \subset Z(X)$ be subgroup generated by $[S \cap \{0\} \times X]-[S \cap \{1\} \times X]$ for irreducible subvarieties $S \subset \mathbb P^1\times X$, not lying in one layer of this product. Then $A(X)=Z(X)/Rat(X)$ is Chow group, and may be equipped with ring structure.

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a closed morphism of smooth varieties. Then one can pushforward cycle $Z$ on $X$ to either 0 if $\dim f(X)<\dim X$ or to $[K(Z):K(f(Z))] f(Z)$ otherwise. It seems clearly that for closed $f$ $Rat(X)$ will be sent to $Rat(Y)$, am I wrong?

Comment: Consider the closed morphism $f: \mathbf A^1 \rightarrow \text{Spec } k$. The divisor of a nonconstant regular function on $\mathbf A^1$ will push forward to a nonzero cycle on $\text {Spec } k$. But $\text{Rat}(\text{Spec }k)$ is trivial.

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken, but a PDF of the book can also be found at https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf.